# How to prevent HREF (which calls JS function) from being triggered when "Enter" key is pressed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am facing a problem.

I have a href which calls a javascript function "delete_element_on_page" when i click on it.

So when i click the HREF with my mouse, everything is fine and the function gets called.

However, because the HREF has focus, if keep hitting my enter key, the function gets called again and again and again leading to undesired outcomes.

How can i prevent this from happening?

I was thinking of 
1. Blurring the focus on the href when my function is called
--> I could do this, but this will mean I have to manually do this for every single HREF because jquery.blur can only be triggered at an individual element level.
--> Alternatively, is there a javascript equivalent of where I can do a universal Blurring, regardless of which element is in focus?

OR

1. Deactivate enter key from triggering clicking of a HREF
   --> Is this even possible? And if so, worth my while in terms of code complexity / compatibility etc..

Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 1):

You can bind your event and avoid placing the javascript trigger inside the html tag.

With jQuery (the easy and more reliable way) you do that like this:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $("#myelementid").bind("click",function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); // important, to prevent trigering the default a href

        // your code goes here

        $(this).blur();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: thank you! I didnt know that binding this way would result in a different behaviour with regards to "enter" key.

Answer (score 1):

The above answers will block both keyboard click and mouse click this will block the enter key from doing anything on that link.  So it corresponds to #2

```
<a id="fail" href="http://jquery.com">default click action is prevented</a>
<script>
$("#fail").keydown(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can bind click event handle it by jquery, using href for calling js functions is not recommended:

```
$("a#id").click(function(){

 // the code goes here;

})
```

Comment: thank you! I didnt know that binding this way would result in a different behaviour with regards to "enter" key.